# Powershell fastest directory list

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Anyone know a fast way to do a recursive directory listing? I am trying to go through a SAN of about 10tb and "get-childitem -include" takes days to run... I know there will be no way to bring it down to minutes but perhaps some way to cut the time to a few hours would be great. I only need a list i can sort through don't need the file properties as I will be using this to find certain types of files on our SAN such as PST files.

If anyone could point me in the direction on how to use the compiled code from [HERE](http://www.leporelo.eu/blog.aspx?id=powershell-performance-comparison-compiled-code-cmdlet-or-net-call) I should be good too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just one extension that you're after use the Filter parameter, it's much faster than  -Include. I'd also suggest to use PowerShell 3 is you can (get-childitem has the new -file switch), as far as I remember listing UNC paths performance was enhanced in it (with underlying .net 4 support).

Another option would be to use the dir command from a cmd window, should be very fast.

Comment: yes but unfortunately any file path over 255 characters can't be displayed. If there was a way around this limitation I would be using the DIR Command.

Comment: see if this helps http://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/01/list-all-files-regardless-of-260-character-path-restriction-using-powershell-and-robocopy/

Comment: never thought of using robocopy as an alternative, its gunna take some time to play with but just doing a simple run of my C:\ it runs about 13x faster that get-childitem!

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a day late and a dollar short but you can use robocopy for this purpose and it will list paths longer than 255 chars:

`robocopy <SourceRoot> <DummyDestinationDir> /MIR /FP /NC /NS /NDL /NJH /NJS /LOG:<LogFilePath> /L`

I know it's pretty wordy but robocopy is very quick compared to PowerShell, though I don't know how it would stack up against cmd's dir.  You can either redirect std out using ">" or site the /LOG: parameter like above.  I would test to see which is faster.  Note do not use the /TEE option console output slows robocopy down in my experience.  Also note the file paths will be indented in the output but this is easily rectified with a text editor than can trim leading and/or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

As Shay sys, Powwershell V3 is much better than v2.

If you just want a list of the file's fullnames, the legecy dir command with a /B (bare) switch is still faster than get-childitem

```
cmd /c dir <root path> /B /S /A-D
```